# Multiple <ESC> with a single <ESC>

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, plugin-deoplete

How can I get the effect of multiple `<ESC>`s being pressed when I press `<ESC>` once?

My current config requires me to press `<ESC>` twice to switch to Normal mode: once to close the completion pop-up and again to switch to Normal mode.

This is what I tried (and it didn't work):

```
:imap <ESC> <ESC><ESC>
```

Note: I am using NeoVim version 0.2.2

Answer (score 3):

For future references, I would suggest you to always use `noremap` version of vim keymapping. Otherwise, the mappings get remapped. For example when you map like this:

```
:imap <Esc> <Esc><Esc>
```

Your mapped `<Esc>` gets again mapped to two more `<Esc>`. So it would probably be recursive. So, instead do this:

```
:inoremap <Esc> <Esc><Esc>
```

This will cancel remapping in the mapped keys.

Comment: After using this mapping, arrow keys insert capital B,D, etc in insert mode. Is it possible to not have it that way? Am using Mac OS. Thanks!